# How to improve an attraction "hotspot"?

Tags: website-design, patterns, color-theory

I am trying to draw the viewers' eyes to the 'join now' button in the image below. My idea was to represent this with a series of 'waves' coming into a 'hot spot' in the middle. This concept should make you feel like clicking the 'join now' button.

I need some fresh reviews on my idea and if it's correctly implemented. I'm a coder, not a designer, but love good design. Could I get some feedback on this image?

[image]

Note: the border on the right is faded, as to indicate the last image in a series of frontage slideshow.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the question is. Would I click that? Well, that's less about the design and more about the previous set of slides and if I was sold on the sales pitch. Purely from a visual POV, I'd suggest making the link bigger, and ideally much higher contrast (use a bolder typeface, for instance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you need this for exactly? There many ways to attract the viewer, but it's easier if you know what you´re building for.

In general, you can assume the user reads from the top left corner to the bottom right ([Gutenberg Diagram](http://www.studiodino.com/images/gutenberg.jpg)). Therefore the bottom left corner is a very weak area, and if you put something there it might get overlooked.

Another good example is [this](http://www.geoworldonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Effective-Coming.jpg). By creating something like a pyramid you guide the user from the top to the bottom, where the bottom part should be a call to action (like on the picture).

And of course, you can also do something like you made in the image you posted, using some radial gradient with something in the middle. However, if it's for the web, i'd suggest you make a big button around it so it has a bit more surface to click and is easier to see.

Comment: thx great addition, yes I'm building a social media related site I think about the pyramid and the text formatting will be changed to be nicer ;p